Eckmann-Hilton argument on 2-cells of (strict) 2 categories
I think this is a really silly question, but I am indeed confused: in 2(strict) category $C$, the two cells (behaving like natural transformations in $2Cat$) has two ways of compositions, which are 'vertical composition' $\circ$ and 'horizontal composition' $\circ_{2}$, moreover, such two compositions satisfy several properties, one of which is distributivity of $\circ$ and $\circ_{2}$.
If we consider the set of 2 cells, then if we apply the Eckmann-Hilton argument, then shouldn't we get the conclusion that such two compositions are the same and also commutative, which is absurd?

Incidentally, ChatGPT o1-mini (released very recently) is capable of answering this question correctly.

The Eckmann–Hilton argument applies to a set equipped with two monoid structures. So, for a fixed object $A$ in a 2-category, we can consider the set of endo-2-cells of $1_A$. This has two monoid structures, given by horizontal and vertical composition. Consequently, by the Eckmann–Hilton argument, these monoid structures are the same and are commutative.
However, we cannot apply the same argument to show that horizontal and vertical composition are the same in general, because they do not define monoids: they define categories. If you try to be precise about applying the Eckmann–Hilton argument, you will see it doesn't make sense if you don't restrict to a single object as we did above (as it is this that ensures we have monoid structures with the same underlying set).
